# Changing a business object in an Adapter

Tags: android, json, android-adapter

I'm building an android app similar to Facebook (gets a newsfeed stored in db from a REST API), and I am now implementing a reddit-like voting system, in which every feed item has a vote state (none, up, down) stored in db.

When I do retrieve the newsfeed json, i set its voteState to the vote state in the json, then I display it through a newsfeed adapter.

But if i set the voteState in the newsfeed adapter to another value (based on an onClickListener), this changed value does not reach the actual newsfeed.
This is because every time I scroll the newsfeed, the newsfeed adapter gets a new instance of the newsfeed, and doesn't care about the value I changed.

Thus, I'm looking for the best way to modify permanently the newsfeed vote state from the newsfeed adapter (this can be generalized to any variable assigned to an ArrayList and then displayed through an ArrayListAdapter).

If you have any suggestions, please feel free to respond.

Thank you :)

EDIT :

```
public class NewsfeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsfeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Newsfeed newsfeed;
private FeedItem item;

public NewsfeedAdapter(..., Newsfeed newsfeed) {
    ...;
    this.newsfeed = newsfeed;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected Button button_up/down....

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        button = findViewById ... (R.id.button);
        ...
    }

}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FeedItem item = newsfeed.get(position);

    holder.button_up.setTag(position);
    holder.button_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeVote(item, "up");
        }
    });

    holder.button_down.setTag(position);
    holder.button_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeVote(item, "down");
        }
    });
}

public void changeVote(FeedItem item, String flag) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "State of vote :" + item.getVoteState());
    if (item.getVoteState().equals(flag)) {
        item.setVoteState("none");
        Log.d(TAG, "Deleting vote :" + item.getVoteState());
        new Connexion(activity, fragment, "vote", "Deleting vote...").execute(String.valueOf(item.getId()), flag, "delete");
    }
    else if (item.getVoteState().equals("none")){
        item.setVoteState(flag);
        Log.d(TAG, "Voting :" + item.getVoteState());
        new Connexion(activity, fragment, "vote", "Voting...").execute(String.valueOf(item.getId()), flag, "insert");

    } else {
        item.invertVoteState(flag);
        Log.d(TAG, "Inverting :" + item.getVoteState());
        new Connexion(activity, fragment, "vote", "Voting...").execute(String.valueOf(item.getId()), flag, "invert");
    }
} }
```

Comment: Please post your adapter code so that we can see what you have to far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Send updates to the rest API every time a piece of data is changed. This is really expensive and not something you want to do most likely.

2) Create a local data layer between your rest API and your listview - most likely an SQLite database or some other ORM lib. This way you can hold an instance of the DB in your adapter, and whenever a piece of data changes, you can update that through a simple db method call, and then periodically send updates to the rest API, while also checking for new updates from the rest API and then pushing them to the DB.

I would highly recommend using an SQLite DB, as you can keep a counter in your DB code of a certain number of changes, or time passed since last sync, and keep the data the user is seeing up to date with out smashing the users data usage with repeated network calls.

Comment: I've spotted this way of doing things a long time ago, and now I am regretting why I didn't do this in the first place. Any way of quickly implementing this right with a good ORM lib ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I've always used the SQLiteDatabase that is built into android because it is quite simple. If this is suficient please accept this answer!